# How can I get latest employee ID (string) from the list of employees using .net web api Get call

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am using Entity Framework 
My EmployeeDto class is :

```
public class EmployeeDto
    {
        [DataMember]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My Dto class is EmployeeDto and Dal class is named as Employee. I want to get the maximum value of EmployeeID from the database and provide it to frontend through Get call .

My Get call to get the list of all employees is :

```
public List<EmployeeDto> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            var employeeDto = new List<EmployeeDto>();
            using (EmployeeDataEntities entities = new EmployeeDataEntities())
            {
                var employeeData = entities.Employees.ToList().Where(e => e.IsActive == true);

                List<Employee> emp = employeeData.ToList(); 
                //emp.FindLastIndex(e => e.)
                employeeDto = Mapper.Map<List<Employee>,List<EmployeeDto>>(emp);
            };
            return employeeDto;
        }
```

This is my GetLatestEmployeeByID code :

```
public int GetEmployeeLatestID(EmployeeDto employeeDto)
        {
            using (EmployeeDataEntities entities = new EmployeeDataEntities())
            {
                var employeeData = entities.Employees.ToList().Where(e => e.IsActive == true);
                List<Employee> emp = employeeData.ToList();
                emp.FindLastIndex(e => e.ID);                              
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since the ID is `string` you need to explain what that ID looks like. If no relational operation on that string makes sense, then it's impossible to use for your requirement. For example if the id is a GUID - there is no way to say ID A is "newer" than ID B. Whereas if IDs are just numbers (that are created in a strictly ascending order and unique) stored as string , then there's hope.

Comment: Id examples: AB01, AB02, AB03 . now i want the maximum id which will be AB03 and want to return this value through get call @Fildor

Comment: Is the "AB" part fix or can there be for example "AC01" ?

Comment: Its fixed @Fildor

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case but you can use "FindLastIndex()" or if you know that there wouldn't be many records you can reverse and get first record, this will always be the biggest ID

Comment: @FilipYordanov Only if the List is sorted by ID.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i use "FIndLastIndex()" in my code. I am supposed to use that only but i dont know how to do it . Plase tell how to do it ? @FilipYordanov

Comment: @UV009 Does the order of SerialNumber always match the order of ID? That is: Is it possible to have Serial / ID : 0 / AB03 , 1 / AB01 ?

Comment: No not necessary. Serial Number is autogenerated and it doesnt match the order with ID @Fildor

Comment: You can order by whatever you want and you can FindLastIndex by whatever you want. FindLastIndex argument is Predicate<T> so. Still though, sorry if I misunderstood your question in that case, my apologies

Comment: Hi i am using this in get latest employee by id but its not correct implementation -- please tell

public int GetEmployeeLatestID(EmployeeDto employeeDto)
        {
            using (EmployeeDataEntities entities = new EmployeeDataEntities())
            {
                var employeeData = entities.Employees.ToList().Where(e => e.IsActive == true);
                List<Employee> emp = employeeData.ToList();
                emp.FindLastIndex(e => e.ID);             
            }
        }
@FilipYordanov

Comment: Can you add your ("not correct") attempt? Maybe it's just a minor bug, we can easily help you fix.

Comment: @UV009 To add code / information to your question use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49190075/edit) link instead of comments.

Comment: Yeah i did it . Please check. Actually I am new here.@Fildor

Comment: One more thing I have to return only the integer value of the employeeID. Please help @Fildor

Comment: var biggestId = emp.Max(x => Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x.ID).Sum(y => y)); -> try this

Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x.ID) - returns a byte array  of the ID
.Sum(y => y) -> sum the bytes 
emp.Max() -> will return the biggest depends on the ascii soo i have tried with "AB01" , "AB02" and "AB03" and it works

Comment: I don't understand this code you have written @FilipYordanov.
What is Sum(y => y) doing ?

Comment: This is a good approach, it worked for me but a complex one as it will sum up the ascii value of the employeeID . If the count of employees increases it's time taking approach. 
Can you help me out by using FindLastIndex() method ?@FilipYordanov

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a couple of solutions and i end up with this one:

```
var a = new List<EmployeeDto>()
        {
            new EmployeeDto()
            {
                SerialNumber = 1,
                ID = "AB01",
                FirstName = "Ala",
                MiddleName = "b",
                LastName = "ala"
            },
            new EmployeeDto()
            {
                  SerialNumber = 2,
                ID = "AB02",
                FirstName = "Ala",
                MiddleName = "b",
                LastName = "ala"
            },new EmployeeDto()
            {
                  SerialNumber = 3,
                ID = "AB03",
                FirstName = "Ala",
                MiddleName = "b",
                LastName = "ala"
            }
        };

        // biggestIdAsInt = 230 a.max returns the max value after the calculations 
        var biggestIdAsInt = a.Max(employee => Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(employee.ID) // get Employee Id as byte array
        .Sum(b => b)); // summ the bytes for each employee 

        // 230


var substractedNumberFromBiggestId = Regex.Match(a.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToCharArray().Sum(y => y) == biggestIdAsInt).ID, @"\d+").Value;
        Console.WriteLine(substractedNumberFromBiggestId);
```

I have put comments to make the code a little bit clearer.

Comment: Its returning 230 but how to get the employee id integer value that is 03

Comment: i edited my code, last line can proved you only the numbers from the Id, hope that end your problem :)

Comment: Will this work for the first entry I want to make ?
Suppose I want to add "AB01" as the first entry and I want it to be shown in the frontend .

Comment: I guess so, you can try i mean i's not so deep in what do you want to do and how you will manage the code, but the last line i added you can debug and look what's happening, you can also just fine the ID without removing the AB so you can return "AB03" and you can consume it at the front end... I mean it depends on your business key.. :)